# Fluid TYPO3 : Error after Update : Could not analyse class:FluidTYPO3\Flux\ViewHelpers\Flexform\SheetViewHelper maybe not loaded or no autoloader?

Tags: typo3, fluid, autoloader, flux, viewhelper

Aargh! My `TYPO3 6.2.11` worked fine! Then I was updated all of my `FLUIDTYPO3-Extensions` and now I'll get an error:

```
Could not analyse class:FluidTYPO3\Flux\ViewHelpers\Flexform\SheetViewHelper maybe not loaded or no autoloader?
```

Here's the [changelog](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/blob/development/CHANGELOG.md), but there is no obvious problem for me? FluidTYPO3:

```
flux 7.1.2 => 7.2.0
fluidcontent_core 1.0.3 => 1.1.0
fluidcontent 4.1.1 => 4.1.2
fluidpages 3.1.2 => 3.2.0
vhs 2.3.0 => 2.3.1
```

I change my namespaces at all templates and FLUX-FCEs `xmlns:f` but that won't help. From

```
xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
```

to

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
     xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Flux/ViewHelpers"
     f:schemaLocation="https://fluidtypo3.org/schemas/fluid-master.xsd"
     xmlns:flux="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Flux/ViewHelpers"
     flux:schemaLocation="https://fluidtypo3.org/schemas/flux-master.xsd">
```

Nothing.

It's a disaster ... my Website is crashed with that error.
I hope someone can help me ... (Never update later then 10pm ;)

Comment: Never update in a live environment (even before 10pm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no longer a Flexform Namespace in Flux.

Change your ViewHelper to

```
<flux:form.sheet .... >
...
</flux:form.sheet .... >
```

This has to be done for all ViewHelpers that use the old `<flux:flexform`... namespace.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for your help. I've changed my code. Everything is fine ..  puuuh ;)

Answer (score 0):

On my 6.2 system with
fluidpages  3.2.3
flux    7.2.1 
vhs     2.3.3

it finally worked with:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
xmlns:v="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers"
xmlns:flux="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Flux/ViewHelpers">
```

I got this out of the extension built with the builder extension - the code given in the documentation did not work. (I only used Fluid pages, no Fluid content)

Some additional example to the above for the whole template:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
xmlns:v="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers"
xmlns:flux="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Flux/ViewHelpers">

<f:layout name="Default" />

<f:section name="Configuration">

    <flux:form id="default">

        <!-- Input field for Fluid variable 'pageClass' -->
        <flux:field.input name="settings.pageClass" default="onecol"/>

        <!-- Backend layout grid (TYPO3 6.x and greater only) -->
        <flux:grid>
            <flux:grid.row>
                <flux:grid.column colPos="0" name="Main" style="width: 75%" colspan="4" />

            </flux:grid.row>
        </flux:grid>

    </flux:form>

</f:section>



<f:section name="Body">

    <div class="container content">
        <div class="col-full">
         <!-- Render colPos=0 in this section -->
                <v:content.render column="0"/>    
        </div>
    </div>    

</f:section>

</div>
```

I don't wanna know how many hours of developer time these changes in conventions burn every time...
Good luck!